# What is wrong with how I create this variable for summoner from the Riot API?

Tags: php, arrays, riot-games-api

`enter code here`The error this code returns is

> "Trying to get property of non-object" or "Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$name".

The variable **$summoner** is what does not work. Assume the variables sID, $lcaseregion and $APIkey (etc.) are all properly set.

```
    <?php
    $summonerURL = "https://$lcaseRegion.api.pvp.net/api/lol/$lcaseRegion/v1.4/summoner/" . $sID . "?api_key=9" . $APIkey;
    $responseSummoner = @file_get_contents($summonerURL);
    $summoner = @json_decode($responseSummoner);
    echo print_r($summoner); //this works and prints things
    echo $summoner->name; //this does not work
    echo $summoner->profileIconId; //this also does not work.
    //please find print_r results below...
    ?>
```

**print_r results;**

```
stdClass Object ( [41245441] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 41245441 [name] => Bubbalubagus [profileIconId] => 558 [revisionDate] => 1488775287000 [summonerLevel] => 30 ) )
```

Any other advice and tips you can give me on how the arrays work would also be appreciated.

Comment: Success on this question, to me, means successfully printing profileIconId (a number) and name as well as any other contents in the stdClass object array.

Comment: this is object of object, try it with `foreach` or `pop`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$summoners = @json_decode($responseSummoner);
foreach($summoners as $summoner){
    echo $summoner->name;
    echo $summoner->profileIconId;
}
```

As it was pointed out already, you need to loop through the found summoners (although it is only one)

//EDIT: saw an object that wasnt there, this works now